# Magento Email and Opensearch connectivity issue

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, opensearch, elasticsearch-7, magento2.4

I have bought a fiber theme from the themeforest, I've installed it on my AWS EC2 ubuntu 22.04 machine.

I choose a fiber quickstart installation process which was came up with a magento 2.4.5 version.

Now I'm facing two problems;

1. is **the AWS opensearch / elasticsearch** is not connecting and giving a "**no alive node found**" error.
2. When I tried to configure the **godaddy SMTP** sto setup the email functionality, I've found that the default plugin contains only **Disable Email Communications, Host, Port & Set Return-Path** fields only instead of **host, port, ssl type, username and passwords** fields.
3. for the **AWS Opensearch / Elasticsearch** I tried to connect it via kibana and it was connected also I tried it to connect via curl by using username and password and it was connected.
4. For the SMTP, I did tried the **magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp** package but it was giving me the 404, I checked the package and it was not exists anymore now, then I tried the manual installation by download the zip file and after it I got the magpal SMTP option in my magento admin, and look what, after I filled all the req fields, I got the following error **cannot connect to host; error = stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net:465 (Unknown error) (errno = 0 )**.

I had double checked the the opensearch credentials and smtp credentials and it was correct, also I checked the **AWS EC2 firewalls** which was already inactive, **security group & VPC inbound and outbound rules** which is temporally made **allow for all rule**. I've got a green light from the godaddy support team too, that no port is blocked from their side.

IDK what's is the issue of these two things,

Thanks